# Automatically update query in access

Tags: ms-access

I have data in a table and a query to run in access. I want the query to update itself as and when the data is changed in the table. Is it possible to do so in access?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Queries don't contain data, they pull data out of tables. As such, they should always update themselves.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Refresh-or-requery-data-76e8c8b5-b8b4-49eb-a7d5-a472e742366c

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy thing to do, but it can be done. My approach would be the following (if you really want to do this):

1 Create a VBA function that opens and closes the query

```
Public Function RefreshQuery() As Integer
    DoCmd.Close acQuery, "QueryA"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "QueryA"
End Function
```

2 Create a data macro on update, change and insert for your relevant table that calls this VBA function by using SetLocalVar to set a local variable equal to it's result

This has numerous disadvantages, such as calling focus to the query every time the table is changed.

I'm not going in to much detail here, because I guess you won't implement this as its use case is limited.